# Play2 run via Sbt in dev mode on Osx Causes Out of Memory

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I can't seem to find similar issues.
On OSX, play2 bin seems to run okay but using sbt causes oom errors and scala files never complete compiling

> --- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
>
> [info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 9000...
>   (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
>
> [info] Compiling 15 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to
>   /Users/tripled153/Development/src/Foundation/playApp/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Exception
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurred dispatching signal Unknown Signal
>   to handler- the VM may need to be forcibly terminated

I'm running with extended memory settings but still no luck. Running in staged (prod) mode appears okay though.

rundev.sh

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx3536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxPermSize=512M" 
sudo sbt clean run
```

Comment: Same on Linux, just do a ctrl-c, ctrl-d, or, in rare, case kill -9 the running process, and get back at it.  I've noticed that this happens mostly when doing a lot of code-change/browser-refresh cycles. Play 2.1 may have made improvements in this area, or at least one would hope ;-)

Comment: That sucks. Ya staging for prod works okay. It's funny because play binary is actually using sbt but they don't behave the same.